# How to "carry" covariance through multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, covariance

I've got an interface structure that looks like this:

At the most basic level is an IDataProducer  with this definition:

```
public interface IDataProducer<out T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetRecords();
}
```

and an IDataConsumer that looks like this:

```
public interface IDataConsumer<out T>
{
    IDataProducer<T> Producer { set; }
}
```

Finally, I've got an IWriter that derives off of IDataConsumer like so:

```
public interface IWriter<out T> : IDataConsumer<T>
{
    String FileToWriteTo { set; }

    void Start();
}
```

I wanted to make IWriter's generic type T covariant so that I could implement a Factory method to create Writers that could handle different objects without having to know what type would be returned ahead of time. This was implemented by marking the generic type "out". The problem is, I'm having a compile error on IDataConsumer because of this:

```
Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'IDataConsumer<T>.Producer'. 'T' is covariant.
```

I'm not really sure how this can be. It looks to me like the generic type is marked as covariant through the whole chain of interfaces, but it is very possible I don't totally understand how covariance works. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your `Producer` property is write-only. That is, you are actually using `T` in a contravariant way, by passing the value that is generic on type `T` *into* the implementer of the interface, rather than the implementer passing it out.

One of the things I like best about the way the C# language design team handled the variance feature in generic interfaces is that the keywords used to denote covariant and contravariant type parameters are mnemonic with the way the parameters are used. I always have a hard time remembering what the words "covariant" and "contravariant" mean, but I never have any trouble remembering what `out T` vs. `in T` means. The former means that you promise to only return `T` values from the interface (e.g. method return values or property getters), while the latter means that you promise to only accept `T` values into the interface (e.g. method parameters or property setters).

You broke that promise by providing a setter for the `Producer` property.

Depending on how these interfaces are implemented, it's possible what you want is `interface IDataConsumer<in T>` instead. That would at least compile. :) And as long as the `IDataConsumer<T>` implementation really is only consuming the `T` values, that would probably work. Hard to say without a more complete example.

Comment: There was considerable debate over what terms to use; I too am very happy that we settled on "in" and "out".

Comment: +1 for the answer (and the handy mnemonic). Unfortunately I can't get rid of the producer setter, so there's clearly something wrong with my architecture. But that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @redsoxfantom: _"so there's clearly something wrong with my architecture"_ -- maybe there is, maybe not. If you change the declaration as I suggest above, i.e. to `interface IDataConsumer<in T>`, the code would compile. So as long as you're not actually trying to do something like assigning a more-derived `IDataConsumer<T>` to a less-derived one (e.g. not doing `IDataConsumer<Mammal> m = new TigerConsumer();` as in Eric's example), everything's fine. Whether something is actually _wrong_ per se depends on what the rest of the code looks like, and we don't have that information.

Comment: @EricLippert: What alternatives were considered?

Comment: @Brian https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/31/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-eight-syntax-options/

Answer (score 7):

Peter's answer is correct. To add to it: it helps to try out some examples and see what goes wrong. Suppose the code you had originally was allowed by the compiler.  We could then say:

```
class TigerConsumer : IDataConsumer<Tiger> 
{
    public IDataProducer<Tiger> p;
    public IDataProducer<Tiger> Producer { set { p = value; } }
    ... and so on ...
}
class GiraffeProducer : IDataProducer<Giraffe> 
{ 
  public IEnumerable<Giraffe> GetRecords() { 
    yield return new Giraffe(); 
  }

TigerConsumer t = new TigerConsumer();
IDataConsumer<Mammal> m = t;        // compatible with IDataConsumer<Mammal>
m.Producer = new GiraffeProducer(); // compatible with IDataProducer<Mammal>
foreach(Tiger tiger in t.p.GetRecords()) 
  // And we just cast a giraffe to tiger
```

Every step on the way here is perfectly typesafe but the program is plainly wrong. Either one of those conversions has to be illegal, or one of the interfaces is not safe for covariance. We wish all those conversions to be legal, and therefore we must detect the lack of type safety in your interface declarations.

Comment: Ah, alright then now I see the issue. Can you recommend any good beginner reading on covariance / contravariance? I had a look at the MSDN documentation and found it a little over my head.

Comment: @redsoxfantom: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A88656+covariance

Comment: @redsoxfantom: My notes on the design and implementation of the feature start here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/

Comment: @redsoxfantom: All my MSDN blog articles on the subject, in newest-to-oldest order. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/Covariance-and-Contravariance/

Comment: @redsoxfantom: My post-Microsoft blog articles: https://ericlippert.com/category/covariance-and-contravariance/

Comment: @EricLippert Doesn't the `foreach` loop in your example do an implicit cast, which makes it unclear whether type-safety was broken in the language or would be correctly caught at runtime? If your example was `Tiger tiger = t.p.GetRecords().First();` that would show that type-safety was clearly broken.

Comment: @CarlWalsh: Correct, a foreach introduces an implicit cast. Your example would be better, yes.